# hidden field passes all params as strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing

I have a controller called "Questions" with two actions, "practice" and "grade" both are get routes, the practice view renders a small sample of of Questions and uses forms to get user answers using submit to get the "grade path"

to grade it, I need the record objects to be passed as an array, but when passed using the hidden field I get the reference numbers as strings and not the actual object. how do i get the object so I can call question_object.answer

controllers/questions.rb

```
def practice
   @questions = Questions.find(params[:id])
   @sample_array =  @questions.multiple_choices.sample(params[:number_of_multiple_choices].to_i)
   @sample_array += @questions.true_falses.sample(params[:number_of_true_falses].to_i)
   @user_answers = Array.new(@questions.size, 1)
end

def grade
   @questions = Questions.find(params[:id])
   @sample_array = params[:sample_array]
   @array_answers = # create array based on sample_array's answers
   @user_answers = params[:user_answers].split(' ')
   @user_answers = @user_answers.map.with_index{|x,y| params[("user_answer#{y.to_s}")] }
end
```

views/questions/practice.html.erb # don't mind the finite number of forms its just for example.

```
<%= form_for :grade, :url => grade_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:sample_array, @sample_array) %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:user_answers, @user_answers) %>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= select_tag(("user_answer#{0}"), options_for_select([["a", 1],[ "b", 2],[ "c", 3],[ "d", 4]], 1), class: "form-control") %>
  <%= select_tag(("user_answer#{1}"), options_for_select([["a", 1],[ "b", 2],[ "c", 3],[ "d", 4]], 1), class: "form-control") %>
  <%= select_tag(("user_answer#{2}"), options_for_select([["a", 1],[ "b", 2],[ "c", 3],[ "d", 4]], 1), class: "form-control") %>
  <%= select_tag(("user_answer#{3}"), options_for_select([["a", 1],[ "b", 2],[ "c", 3],[ "d", 4]], 1), class: "form-control") %>
</div>
<div id="finalscore">
  <%= button_to "act_2", class:'btn btn-success' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

in grade the parameters i passed are just strings like so. questions: ["#", "#", "#"]

I researched it and hidden_fields will pass query_strings and that's why im only getting strings, but I can't find any examples on how to obtain the array object to use in my grade controller action.

thanks in advance sorry for the long question I don't know how else to ask about this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the arrays in your `practice` method, why don’t you create them in your `grade` method? To do this, you can instead assign `@number_of_multiple_choice` and `@number_of_true_false` in your `practice` method, pass those numbers in the hidden field tag, and determine your arrays in the `grade` action. I’m actually not sure what you’re trying to do with `@user_answers` in the `practice` action - I assume you’re just trying to create one empty answer object, but it does not appear to be used that way in the form.

**controllers/questions.rb**

```
def practice
   @question = Question.find(params[:id])
   @number_of_multiple_choices =             params[:number_of_multiple_choices].to_i
   @number_of_true_falses = params[:number_of_true_falses].to_i
end

def grade
 @question = Question.find(params[:id])
 @sample_array =   @questions.multiple_choices.sample(params[:number_of_multiple_choices].to_i)
 @sample_array += @questions.true_falses.sample(params[:number_of_true_falses].to_i)
 @array_answers = # create array based on sample_array's answers
 @user_answers = params[:user_answers].split(' ')
 @user_answers = @user_answers.map.with_index{|x,y| params[("user_answer#{y.to_s}")] }
end
```

**views/questions/practice.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :grade, :url => grade_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:number_of_multiple_choice, @number_of_multiple_choice) %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:number_of_true_falses, @number_of_true_falses) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Additionally I noticed you’re saying `@questions = Questions.find(params[:id]`. The `.find` is meant to return one record but you have a) pluralized your variable indicating you want multiple questions, and b) pluralized your model, which is not standard convention. Either your model should be renamed or that will throw an error if your model is actually not pluralized.

Comment: the naming conventions are irrelevant because in my app they're named right i built this controller and view on the fly to represent a simplified version.

as for building the arrays in grading its impossible because arrays are a sample of a bigger array. and randomized if its sampled again its a completely different array.

Comment: got ya, I recommend then in your question you include example code as close to the actual code as you can. Otherwise people may not to be able to give you the answer you need. From your current example code, I have no way of knowing that you have "named your models correctly". Additionally, from the example code it would appear that the `practice` action is simply passing the arrays on, and the view isn't actually using the arrays. If that's not the case, then additional code should be added to show that.